# LINQ group lists

Tags: c#, linq

In LINQ is it possible to group a unique sequence of an ints? Say I have a class each with a property that is a List. Each object(say its called foo) has one of these lists of ints {1}, {1, 2, 4}, {4, 5, 6}, {1}, {1, 2, 4}. How would I use a group by so I get these groups:

```
List<foo> foos// has 5 elements

/*
groups:
1. 2 {1}
2. 2 {1. }
3. {4, 5, 6}

*/
```

Comment: you should actually sketch out these classes. It is very hard t follow what you are trying to do here.

Comment: Can you explain your question? Show us the input and the the expected output, as well as what you have tried.

Comment: The expected output is in the multi line comment. I'll try to elaborate more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to use the [GroupBy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/bb534334(v=vs.100).aspx) overload that receives an IEqualityComparer for the keys.

```
var groups = foos.GroupBy(thefoo => thefoo.IntListProp, new IntListComparer());
```

Where `IntListComparer` is your custom implementation of `IEqualityComparer` that could be something like:

```
class IntListComparer : IEqualityComparer<List<int>> {
    public bool Equals(List<int> x, List<int> y) {
        if (x == y)
            return true;
        if (x == null || y == null)
            return false;
        if (x.Length != y.Length)
            return false;

        using (var xenum = x.GetEnumerator()) {
            foreach (int yval in y) {
                xenum.MoveNext();
                if (yval != xenum.Current)
                    return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    // You also have to implement the GetHashCode which
    // must have the property that
    // if Equals(x, y) => GetHashCode(x) == GetHashCode(y)
    public int GetHashCode(List<int> x) {
        int hashcode = 1;
        const int primeMultiplier = 17;
        foreach (int xval in x)
            hashchode *= primeMultiplier * xval;
        return hashcode;
    }
}
```